# What is the correct way to use flask-mongoengine field kwargs?

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, keyword-argument, flask-mongoengine

I want to set an additional parameter ("order") when defining a MongoEngine field in my Python Model which I can then access in my View.

*Note: "order" is a custom parameter; MongoEngine documentation states that kwargs can added.*

I've tried:

```
class Tasks(Document):
    complete = BooleanField(default=False, **{'order':0})
    task = StringField(max_length=128)
```

The error encountered is:

```
File ".../flask_mongoengine/wtf/base.py", line 23, in __init__
    BaseField.__init__(self, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'order'
```

I've searched the MongoEngine documentation for examples, to no avail. I've also been reading on how to use **kwargs in Python, but am not understanding how to apply.

Can you provide an example of how to include additional parameters to those already in the BaseField?

Comment: The field does not except a keyword argument 'order'. What are you actually trying to archiv with the argument?

Comment: Also, `order=0` will do the same thing as `**{'order':0}`

Comment: Correct:  order=0 does the same a **{'order':0}; my question is how to pass the kwargs when defining the the field. I wasn't sure if it was a syntax problem, or if I have to initialize the custom parameters later in my code so that they are available in the fields.

Answer (score 0):

According to [field description](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#fields) of mongoengine doc, it does't offer `order` argument.

Comment: Correct. "order" is a custom parameter; MongoEngine documentation states that kwargs can added.

Comment: @user1911075 Although `kwargs` can add custom parameters, it's not sure the class can process the parameters.

Comment: @user1911075 If you would offer the custom parameter description is better, maybe mongoengine has other feature can satisfy you.